# What's the earliest model of the MacBook to support Wi-Fi networks transmitting at 5GHz?

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

Is there documentation showing the earliest model of the MacBook (both Pro/Air preferred if possible) to have integrated hardware support for Wi-Fi networks using the 5GHz band?

Comment: Probably all of them. 802.11a was the first spec to use 5GHz & all MacBooks since 2006 have had that spec. If you mean 802.11n, then probably about 2009. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All MacBook models have shipped with support for 5GHz Wi-Fi networks since their first generation.

#### 802.11a

- MacBook (2006)
- MacBook Pro (2006)

#### 802.11n (including draft-n)

- MacBook (Late 2006 thru Mid 2010)
- MacBook Air (2008 thru Mid 2012)
- MacBook Pro (Late 2006 thru Early 2013)

#### 802.11ac

- MacBook (Early 2015 thru Mid 2017)
- MacBook Air (Mid 2013 thru 2020)
- MacBook Pro (Late 2013 thru 2020)

#### 802.11ax

- MacBook Air (M1, 2020)
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)
- MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021)
- MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021)

References:

- https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/macbook-pro-wi-fi-specification-details-dep2ac3e3b51/web
- https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/macbook-air-wi-fi-specification-details-dep97005355c/web
- https://everymac.com/systems/by_capability/macs-with-airport-airport-extreme.html